# Why is it inserting 0's instead of blank spaces into my DB using php?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, integer

I have an insert:

```
$sql = 'INSERT into orders SET 
fax_int_prefix = "'.$_SESSION['fax_int_prefix'].'", 
fax_prefix = "'.$_SESSION['fax_prefix'].'", 
fax_first = "'.$_SESSION['fax_first'].'", 
fax_last = "'.$_SESSION['fax_last'];
```

The value of all of these fields is that they are blank right before the insert. Here is an example of one of them I echo'd out just before the insert:

```
$_SESSION[fax_prefix] =
```

For some reason it inserts the integer 0, instead of a blank value or null, as it should. Why is it inserting 0's instead of blank spaces into my DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the structure of your table. It's possible that it is not of type `char` or `varchar` (or that it is and has a default value set to '0'). To do this you can use [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/), [SQLyog](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/) or other MySql admin programs.

**Edit:** If you want to store integers, but have the option of *no value* then make sure the type is nullable. i.e.: `column_name INT(n) DEFAULT NULL`

Comment: Well, the field is set to integer. I want the information they provide in those fields to be an integer or blank(nothing). Do I really need to change the datatype just to do what I want to do?

Comment: If you want them to be blank instead of 0, make sure you `allow null` for the field.

Comment: They do allow for Null. The Null box is checked in phpmyadmin and the default is set to NULL. How can it still be saving the '0' value if I have those null options set?

Comment: If you are passing an empty string you need to test for that and insert null instead. So your query would read (briefly): `if ($_SESSION['fax_int_prefix'] == '') $query = 'INSERT INTO orders SET fax_int_prefix NULL' // ...`

Comment: Just a further note: Blank strings translate to zero when inserting into an int column in sql. You have to specify null because it's not the same as zero. (A good example is a temperature column. 0°C is freezing. Null is "we don't know the value.")

Answer (score 0):

Check the schema of your database. Most likely they are integer fields or such.

```
SHOW FIELDS FROM orders;
```

or

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE orders;
```

might help. Additionally just printing out a variable is no good check, rather use var_dump().

Comment: What's wrong with using integer fields? I want the information they provide in those fields to be an integer or blank(nothing).